# fetch recebendo http status 0

Tags: javascript, fetch

Criei um pequeno projeto no webstorm com um html que faz um fetch a partir do meu localhost:3340

```
fetch('http://httpbin.org/get')
    .then(
        function(response){
            console.log("response ok");
            return response.json();
        }
    )
    .then(function (json){
            console.log("json ok");
        }
    ).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + error.message);
    });
```

Não consigo descobrir qual a causa do erro **"NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."** aparecendo no console do Firefox. Essa mensagem não me ajuda muito porque me parece meio genética.

O firefox está atualizado na ultima versão

Alguém poderia me apontar um caminho. Como não consigo identificar a causa do problema não consigo estudar uma solução.

gerei o arquivo .har para ver se descobria alguma coisa e acho que esse é o response que eu tenho:

```
"response":{

    **"status":0**,
    "statusText":"",
    "httpVersion":"",
    "headers":[
    ],
    "cookies":[
    ],
    "content":{
        "size":0,
        "encoding":"base64",
        "text":""
    },
    "redirectURL":"",
    "bodySize":-1

}
```

antecipadamente agradeço o apoio !

Comment: Provávelmente é um erro de CORS, olhe no console do navegador que deve exibir um erro.

Comment: @PedroSanção, eu gostaria que fosse porque assim eu teria pelo menos um caminho a seguir, mas não consigo determinar porque a única mensagem que aparece no console do firefox é : **ERROR: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.**

Answer (score 0):

304 não é exatamente um erro. Geralmente ocorre quando o navegador percebe que o recurso solicitado existe em cache, então ele "não faz" a requisição e retorna o dado que já existia em cache.

Comment: Será que eu posso fazer um teste limpando o cache do firefox ? Pode me dizer como eu faço isso? Se não der certo vou incluir isso na postagem principal.

Comment: @PhabioRicard Segue link da comunidade mozilla, com o passo a passo para limpar o cache (https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/kb/como-limpar-cache-firefox)